# How to install Chunky PNG?

Tags: ruby, png, compass-sass

I want to use this Compass plugin https://github.com/aaronrussell/compass-rgbapng

it requires Compass and Chunky Png?

Compass is installed but how to install Chunky PNG?

My OS is Windows 7.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Chunky PNG](http://rubygems.org/gems/chunky_png) is available as a ruby gem.

All you have to do is type `gem install chunky_png` in the command prompt.

The GitHub repo/documentation for the gem is available [here](https://github.com/wvanbergen/chunky_png).